# Do a convergence test for the following series?

Tags: convergence-divergence

$$ 1 - \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{3^2} - \frac{1}{3^3} + \frac{1}{3^4} - ....... ∞ $$

I'm able to construct its general term which is :-

$$ u_n = \left( \frac{-1}{3} \right)^{n-1} $$

But I'm not sure what to do next.

Any help would be highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: sum =$a/(1-r)$.

Comment: @NickLiu What is $a$?

Comment: the first term.

Comment: @NickLiu Messy notation. Wrong too.

Comment: One has to ask: **which series** can you sum?

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
$${\frac {1}{1+x}}=\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }(-x)^{n}\quad {\text{ for }}|x|<1$$

Answer (score 0):

This is nothing but

$$\sum_{k = 0}^{+\infty} \left(-\frac{1}{3}\right)^k$$

Which is nothing but the geometric series.

The result is

$$\frac{1}{1 + \frac{1}{3}} = \frac{1}{\frac{4}{3}} = \frac{3}{4}$$

Hence the series converges.

**Geometric Series**

$$\sum_{k = 0}^{+\infty}\ x^k = \frac{1}{1 - x} ~~~~~~~~~~~ \text{for}\ |x| < 1$$

In your case it's simply $x = -1/3$

So you have to change signs by consequence getting:

$$\sum_{k = 0}^{+\infty} \left(-\frac{1}{3}\right)^k = \frac{1}{1 - \left(-\frac{1}{3}\right)}$$

From which the result above.